# db.entity.find not working on decoding special char value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4

Why Entity.find() not working on special char that decode from url?

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id = null, string id1 = null)
    id = Server.UrlDecode(id);
    //working
    var result = db.Val uePairs.Where(m => m.GroupCd == id && m.ValuePairCd == id1);

    //not working
    sample entity= db.sample.Find(id, id1);
}
```

If id contain any special char like "11/1", it wont able to find any data, but if data doesnt contain any special char, it work well, how to actually make find() work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found the answer

instead of

```
sample entity= db.sample.Find(id, id1)
```

I need to use

```
sample entity= db.sample.Find(new string{ id, id1 })
```